# Posting and parsing data from Android to php

Tags: php, android, sql-server, jakarta-ee

I am collecting some different data into three different variables in my android program which are of different data types.

Now I need to post this data into server where I should be able to parse this data and store them in my local database. I am using php for my server side scripting.

**Can some one give me an example how to do this using httppost?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send request to server and get response json is the best way to implement.

Here is the good example given to send httppost json request to server and handling json response.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Comment: Thanks for that. I have one more. If I need to pass a list how can I do that?
for example,list a has 3 values. All these three should go for same ID.

Answer (score 2):

On the Android-side you should not do [network operations in the main UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729941/1306012).

Android Side:

```
public class SendPOSTRequest extends AsyncTask<List<BasicNameValuePair>, Void, String>
{
    private DefaultHttpClient _httpClient;
    private String _url = "";

    public SendPOSTRequest(String url){
        _url = url;
        _httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(List<BasicNameValuePair>... postParameters) {
        String responseString = "";

        try
        {
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(_url);
            postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters[0]));

            HttpResponse response = _httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            // check if post was successfull
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                entity.writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();

                if (entity != null) {
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

In your Activity you can use the "SendPostRequest"-Class like this:
    SendPOSTRequest webPOSTRequest = new SendPOSTRequest(yourWebURLWithYourPHPFunction);
    List postParams = new ArrayList();
    postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "viperbone"));
    String result = webGetRequestUsersEntries.execute(postParams).get();

On serverside I used php-script with PDO (PHP Data Objects) because [it helpts to protect from sql injection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Serverside PHP-Script:

```
try
{
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=yourWebURL;dbname=yourDBName", username, password);

    # substr(str,pos,len) - Make sure POST-Data aren't too long (255 chars max) because my database-field is 255 chars
    $NameClear = substr($_POST['Name'], 0, 255);

    # named placeholders 
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `yourTableName` (Name) VALUES ( :name )");
    $STH->bindParam(':name', $NameClear);

    # setting the fetch mode
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $STH->execute(); 

    # I return 1 for a successful insertion 
    echo "1";

    $DBH = null;
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {
}
```

I hope it helps...